# Get value of Property in custom class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am creating a proxy in which i am creating a property that gets data from the request body using x-path expression. The property i have written is:

```
<property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="ChannelURI" expression="//xs:ChannelURI" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Now i have called a class mediator to which i am passing the value of this property. So in my class mediator, i have written

```
public String channelUriFromProp = String.valueOf(context.getProperty("ChannelURI"));
```

So now if i pass any string value to the ChannelURI property, I can get that value inside my class mediator string channelUriFromProp.

But the real problem is that when i pass null value in from request

```
<body>
 <p:OpenPublicationSession xmlns:p="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
  <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
  <xs:ChannelURI xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"></xs:ChannelURI>
 </p:OpenPublicationSession>
</body>
```

Then when i print the value of channelUriFromProp in class mediator code i get

```
<xs:ChannelURI xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"/>
```

instead of getting null or empty. Whatam i doing wrong in here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is wrong, it should be like this..

```
<property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"  xmlns:p="XXXXXXXXX"  name="ChannelURI" expression="//p:OpenPublicationSession/xs:ChannelURI"
```

Comment: i have implemented your xpath expression but agin getting same output. Instead of null or empty string i am getting that xml tag <xs:ChannelURI xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"/>

Comment: can you put a log mediator after that property mediator to see what you are getting with that particular property mediator. like ; <log level="custom"><property name ="****" expression=get-property('ChannelURI') /> </log>  the issue is not with classmediator..it is with your xpath

Comment: yes i have put log mediator just after my property mediator and i am getting ChannelURI_Value = <xs:Ch
annelURI xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"/> when i am passing blank data